# In HTML5: Does an example qualify as an <aside />?

Tags: html

What is the proper way to indicate something like an example given a list of definitions?

In the following example (hah) I'm using

```
<aside><h4>Example:</h4><code>
```

to indicate that the italicized text is an example, is this the most syntactically accurate way to do so?

(Also, I know I should be using the dl tag, but that's another step)

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h3>Recipients</h3>
        <p>Comma-delimited list of the roles that will receive notification emails</p>
        <aside><h4>Example:</h4><code>bz,zba,admin,readonly,dept_zoning</code></aside>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3>Trigger</h3>
        <code>Can be null</code>
        <p>Relative-pathed Url that initiates the notification action with bracketed parameters</p>
        <aside><h4>Example:</h4><code>/permits/SetApproval/{id}?approved={approvalstate}</code></aside>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3>Message</h3>
        <p>The message that recipients will receive upon notification action.  Bracketed dynamic parameters will exist as specified in the trigger condition</p>
        <aside><h4>Example:</h4><code>This notification has been sent to inform you that Case Number: {id} has been {approvalstate}</code></aside>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly, no, though it wouldn't be the worst use of `<aside>` either.

The spec says of the `<aside>` element:

> The aside element represents a section of a page that consists of
>   content that is tangentially related to the content around the aside
>   element, and which could be considered separate from that content.

The key words are "tangentially related" and "considered separate", neither of which holds for examples of the definition that precedes it in the document.

I would suggest that the `<figure>` element would be most appropriate.

> The figure element represents some flow content, optionally with a
>   caption, that is self-contained and is typically referenced as a
>   single unit from the main flow of the document.
>
> The element can thus be used to annotate illustrations, diagrams,
>   photos, code listings, etc, that are referred to from the main content
>   of the document, but that could, without affecting the flow of the
>   document, be moved away from that primary content, e.g. to the side of
>   the page, to dedicated pages, or to an appendix.

Comment: I had actually glossed over figure, but you're right, "code listings" is clearly there.

Answer (score 1):

I think that would be acceptable. The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-aside-element) says:

> The aside element represents a section of a page that consists of content that is tangentially related to the content around the aside element, and which could be considered separate from that content. Such sections are often represented as sidebars in printed typography.
>
> The element can be used for typographical effects like pull quotes or sidebars, for advertising, for groups of nav elements, and for other content that is considered separate from the main content of the page.

In other words, it's used for secondary content, that is relevant to the context it is in, but can be removed from the flow without breaking the context. If it is used within an article, it can be "bonus info" related to that article, and if it is used outside, it represents content that is not crucial to the rest of the content itself.

HTML5doctor also has [an excellent article](http://html5doctor.com/aside-revisited/) on aside.

EDIT: That being said, I'm not personally a big fan of just cramming a lot of tags around stuff, when it doesn't strictly need to be in its own container. For a whole block of content, that needs to be styled differently, then yes, but if it's just a single heading or something similar that could stand alone, then I'd leave it at that.

Comment: These were my thoughts as well, but your link to html5doctor actually led me to http://html5doctor.com/downloads/h5d-sectioning-flowchart.png

which seems to indicate that figure is more appropriate

Comment: Ah, neato! My thought is, that an example is not required reading to understand the concept, it is merely extra reading to provide a practical example to summarize an already explained theory, so I put it in the same category as, for example, a "did you know?" box.
Therefore, using the flowchart, I would answer "no" to whether or not it's a required to understand the content, thus ending up with an `<aside/>`.
Technically, I guess both would be acceptable (depends on the content and nature of the example), but I'd be interested in hearing some input from more people.